# Installing textshape package for Microsoft R Open 3.4.4 on Azure ML Studio

Tags: r, package, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to use the R `sentimentr` package on Azure ML Studio. As this package is not supported, I'm trying to install it and its dependencies as described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/execute-r-script#bkmk_AddingANewPackage).

The steps that I have performed are:

- downloaded Windows binaries from the R Open 3.4.4 snapshot at [CRAN time machine](https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine)

  - `sentimentr_2.2.3.zip`
  - `syuzhet_1.0.4.zip`
  - `textclean_0.6.3.zip`
  - `lexicon_0.7.4.zip`
  - `textshape_1.5.0.zip`
- zipped those zip files into a zipped folder `packages.zip`
- uploaded `packages.zip` as a dataset to Microsoft Azure ML Studio

In my ML experiment I connect the `packages.zip` dataset to the "Script Bundle (Zip)" input port on "Execute R Script" and include this code:

```
# install R package contained in src  
install.packages("src/lexicon_0.7.4.zip", 
                 lib = ".", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 verbose = TRUE)  

install.packages("src/textclean_0.6.3.zip", 
                 lib = ".", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 verbose = TRUE)  

install.packages("src/textshape_1.5.0.zip", 
                 lib = ".", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 verbose = TRUE)  

install.packages("src/syuzhet_1.0.4.zip", 
                 lib = ".", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 verbose = TRUE)  

install.packages("src/sentimentr_2.2.3.zip", 
                 lib = ".", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 verbose = TRUE)  

# load libraries
library(sentimentr, lib.loc = ".", verbose = TRUE)
```

The experiment runs successfully, until I include a function from `sentimentr`:

```
mydata <- mydata %>%
  get_sentences() %>%
  sentiment()
```

This gives the error:

> there is no package called 'textshape'

Which is difficult to understand given that the output log does not indicate an issue with the packages:

```
[Information]         The following files have been unzipped for sourcing in path=["src"]:
[Information]                           Name  Length                Date
[Information]         1 sentimentr_2.2.3.zip 3366245 2019-08-07 14:57:00
[Information]         2    syuzhet_1.0.4.zip 2918474 2019-08-07 15:05:00
[Information]         3  textclean_0.6.3.zip 1154814 2019-08-07 15:13:00
[Information]         4    lexicon_0.7.4.zip 4551995 2019-08-07 15:17:00
[Information]         5  textshape_1.5.0.zip  463095 2019-08-07 15:42:00
[Information]         Loading objects:
[Information]           port1
[Information]         [1] "Loading variable port1..."
[Information]         package 'lexicon' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked   
[Information]         package 'textclean' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
[Information]         package 'textshape' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
[Information]         package 'syuzhet' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
[Information]         package 'sentimentr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Has anyone seen this, or similar issues? Is it possible that "successfully unpacked" is not the same as successfully installed and usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now answer my own question thanks to [a hint on Twitter](https://twitter.com/bryan_hepworth/status/1159432174225055749) from @bryan_hepworth.

The R packages were installed correctly, but not in the standard library location. So when a function from `sentimentr` runs, R tries to load the dependency package `textshape`:

```
library(textshape)
```

Which of course does not exist *in the standard location* as Azure ML does not support it.

The solution is to load `textshape` explicitly from its installed location:

```
library(textshape, lib.loc = ".")
```

So the solution is: explicitly load packages that you installed at the start of your R code, rather than letting R try to load them as dependencies, which will fail.